# How to use an existing MasterPage from a WebForms project inside an MVC Area?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am attempting to use an existing MasterPage from a WebForms project and use it with an MVC area added to the same solution.

I've read [this blog](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2011/01/07/Using-Razor-Pages-with-WebForms-Master-Pages.aspx) and I am currently stuck on how to connect the two. I've added the extension methods and all of the items he suggests in the `Shared` folder.

In his example the `Shared/RazorView.aspx` file I get two errors on this line.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial((string) ViewBag._ViewName); %>

`The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context`
`The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context`
```

How do you reference the MasterPage, or setup the views so you can use the MasterPage as partial content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to configure ASP.NET WebForms to know what MVC is in the `Views/web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <pages pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
          pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
          userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <controls>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
    </controls>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

In order to get the `RenderPartial` extension method to work, you also need to add the namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html`.